# how to get dropdown value from left join table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have problem when I get value from left join table, database from product table (https://ibb.co/zbpJP0z )and database from farm table !(https://ibb.co/gMKySpP )

I've tried to get the value from dropdown list, but the value is always from joining table

this is my form code

```
<form class="mb-2" id="addproductform"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="serial-number">Serial Number:</label>
        <select class="serial-number form-control" name="serial-number" class="custom-select mb-3" id="newval">
        <option>Serial Number</option>
                  <?php $q=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT produk.nama FROM produk LEFT JOIN farm ON produk.SN=farm.SN WHERE username=\"$_SESSION[username]\"");
        while($d=mysqli_fetch_row($q)) {
            echo "<option value=$d[0]>$d[0]</option>";
        }    ?>
        </select>
    </div>
 </form>
```

..........................
and this is a jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#save_addPlant").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            console.log("submit productform");
                    $("select.serial-number").change(function(){ 
            var tp = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                });
                  namafarm=$("option:selected").val();
                  console.log(namafarm);
     });

});
```

How can I take a value from farm.SN, while I display produk.nama in the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 places that need change in your code.

1. Your are using 2 class attributes in your select tag.  The second
   class attribute wont work. So you have to combine the 2 class
   attributes into 1.
2. You are only selecting produk.nama column in your select query. You
   must also select produk.SN column.

Replace your **select** block with the code below & check whether it works.

```
<select class="custom-select mb-3 form-control serial-number" name="serial-number" class="" id="newval">
<option>Serial Number</option>
<?php 
    $q = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT produk.SN,produk.nama FROM produk INNER JOIN farm ON produk.SN = farm.SN WHERE username = \"$_SESSION[username]\"" );
    while($d=mysqli_fetch_row($q)) {
        echo "<option value=$d[0]>$d[1]</option>";
    }    
?>
```